# Add app extension attribute in user flow JWT Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am working in Azure AD B2C to add custom extensions per application. Theses extensions must be returned in the jwt when the login is requested by the application.

So I create the extension on the app using the graph api

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{{appid}}/extensionProperties
{
    "name": "name",
    "dataType": "String",
    "targetObjects": [
        "User"
    ]
}
```

Then I associate a value for a specific user

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{userid}}
{
    "extension_{{appid(without dashes}}_name": "1234"
}
```

Now I go on the app manifest to add the optional claim.

```
"optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [
            {
                "name": "extension_{{appid(without dashes}}_name",
                "source": "user",
                "essential": true,
                "additionalProperties": []
            }
        ],
        "accessToken": [
            {
                "name": "extension_{{appid(without dashes}}_name",
                "source": "user",
                "essential": true,
                "additionalProperties": []
            }
        ],
        "saml2Token": []
    },
```

Save but the claim never appear on the jwt token.

I also tried using the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56106717/how-to-pass-custom-extension-attributes-from-azure-active-directory-in-jwt-token) post but didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you’ve used Optional claims setup, which works for AAD but not AAD B2C.

Follow this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-user-flow

If you want to select your custom attribute through the Azure Portal - AAD B2C - User Attributes blade, and the attribute was created via Graph API, you have to recreate it in the Portal for it to reconcile.

You would also need to target the b2c-extensions-app AppId when defining the attribute with Graph API.

Comment: So I absolutely have to use user attributes

Comment: Only if you want it to show in the Portal to configure a User Flow in the Portal. If you just want to create a User Flow via API, or Custom Policy, then you can reference your custom attribute in your flow without having to re-register it in the Azure Portal.

Comment: Using the API to create userflow would allow me to specify specific application extensions 
to put in the token ?

Comment: It does not works "<objectid' is an Azure AD B2C directory. Access to this Api can only be made for an Azure AD directory (non b2c).""

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT This actually works I got the custom attribute in my JWT token, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the claims successfully***

As ***Jas Suri - MSFT*** commented, this will only work if you are adding optional claims to *Azure AD application*.

I created the **`extension`** attribute via **Graph API** like below:

[image]

I associated the above **`extension`** attribute to a specific user like below:

[image]

**Please check whether that **`extension`** attribute is visible in optional claims UI or not and add like below:**

[image]

**When you check the manifest, it will be added automatically like below:**

[image]

**I generated the JWT token using `auth-code` flow via Postman like below:**

[image]

**After decoding the JWT token (ID-Token), I got the claims successfully like below:**

[image]

Comment: That’s for AAD, not AAD B2C.

Comment: Indeed I don't have the token configuration option